# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function initBD() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql

Olá tenho o seguinte código php

```
function updateRecord($email, $score){  

$sql = "UPDATE record set record = $score where email = '$email' ";
$banco-> initBD()->exec($sql); //O Log indica o erro nessa linha

if($banco->rowCount()>0){
    $obj = array("resposta"=>1);
}else{
    $obj = array("resposta"=>2);
}
    $array[] = $obj;

    // json_encode($array);
    echo stripslashes( json_encode($array));
}

function initBD(){
    //servidor online
    $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=> 'SET NAMES UTF8');
    return (new \PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;port=80;dbname=yyyyyy; charset=utf8', 'login', 'senha', $opcoes));
}
```

Não sei se isso é o suficiente para responder a dúvida, mas fico na espera pelo feedback.

Comment: Não é o suficiente, onde está sendo instanciado o objeto "banco" e initDB é um método desse objeto? aparentemente é uma função apenas

Comment: tenta trocar "$banco-> initBD()->exec($sql);" por apenas "initBD()->exec($sql);"

Comment: Quem executa é uma biblioteca no volley. Porém o Log indica que o json foi enviado, no entanto o erro acontece somente nessa parte. Vou tentar a sujestão.

Comment: " Call to a member function initBD() on a non-object", ou seja $banco não é um objeto, porem,  mesmo assim você está tentando acessar um método dele. Por isso perguntei onde está sendo instanciado, mas na verdade, não está. Notei também que no seu código, há uma função com o mesmo nome do método invocado. Foi o código dessa função que você tentou utilizar na linha que deu problema?

Comment: sim por isso só adicionei as duas funções a questão, a linha que indica a chamada do método e o método InitBD()

Comment: Então seria melhor separar e especificar. No primeiro trecho "Linha que falhou:" e "Método chamado:". Mas como disse, o método chamado é irrelevante. $banco não é um objeto. Mostra o trecho onde $banco está sendo definido (Recendo uma instância, ou qualquer coisa). Recomendo também que utilize: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gettype.php e passe $banco como parâmetro, e veja a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, pela boas práticas não seria a melhor forma para uma estrutura de conexão e DML, mas baseado no seu código e com algumas modificação, VEJA:
NOTA: porta do MySQL igual a 80? Não seria 3306 ou outra que não seja a porta 80.

```
    <?php

function updateRecord($email, $score, $database_handle){

$sql = "UPDATE record set record = $score where email = '$email' ";
$count = $database_handle->exec($sql);


if($count > 0){
    $obj = array("resposta"=>1);
}else{
    $obj = array("resposta"=>2);
}
    $array[] = $obj;

    // json_encode($array);
  echo stripslashes( json_encode($array));
}

function initBD(){
    //servidor online
    $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=> 'SET NAMES UTF8');
    $database_handle = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=yyyyyy; charset=utf8', 'login', 'senha', $opcoes);
    return $database_handle;
}
$database_handle = initBD();
updateRecord(email,score, $database_handle);
```